Using `send_headers` action to set `X-Frame-Options` not really working
A large number of client sites are on an NGINX hosting platform and a large number of those sites are using industry specific eComm software... ...the eComm provider is pushing all of their customers to ensure that they've got robust security and the only item we're not in compliance with is X-Frame-Options being set to either SAMEORIGIN or DENY.
Normally, we'd do this with .htaccess but on this host, there is no .htaccess.  So instead we've created a simple plugin that doesn't nothing but set the HTTP header X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN.
if( !function_exists( 'wpse60844_set_xframe' ) ) :
    function wpse60844_set_xframe() {
        header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' );
    }
    add_action( 'send_headers', 'wpse60844_set_xframe', 99 );
endif;

With that above, we can run a check and see if it's listed in the sent headers and it is...
var_dump( headers_list() ) shows me that X-Frame-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN.
However, any site scanner we run, and every browser's DEV tools, don't show that it's set.
Have also already tried to remove_headers() first and then re-set it and have tried to run the function on init instead of send_headers.  Neither of these seem to make a difference.
UPDATE / ANSWER
The code in the question, as it turns out, is fine. It's correct for LAMP stacks and it appears that it just doesn't work on NGINX (LNMP stack) OR it just doesn't work on FlyWheel hosted sites.  (That's yet to be determined because I only have access to NGINX via FlyWheel hosted sites, so I haven't yet been able to test this elsewhere.) Kinda sucks because the whole purpose of the function was to add the header on servers where I don't get to use .htaccess, like FlyWheel, so the one place where I would need this, is the one place it doesn't work.  On all the other LAMP sites we work with, we'd just add it to .htaccess.

your code works on my test website. maybe you have another plugin which interfere with that.

Did you test on NGINX or APACHE?  I'm suspecting that this is more a hosting and caching issue than it is a code issue.  :-(

it is a self hosted apache, I don't have a nginx server ready for tests.

Is your web host unable/unwilling to assist in setting the header? If they lock down nginx config, typically the web host will assist via their support team.

Yeah, they were willing to help.  We have dozens of sites on there though, some need this because the third party 'cart' provider a lot of our clients use now requires this as part of their security audits, so was just looking to avoid having to ask the host to do it on a site by site basis.
